# How get window values in Tests with Enzyme, Jest + Create React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocking, jestjs, enzyme

Due to the build process I'm using to push my app out I'm passing some environment variables in a file after build, which works fine. However it breaks my tests with the following error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'DATA' of undefined

  57 |   Auth: {
  58 |     oth,
> 59 |
     | ^
  60 |    
  61 |     identity: checkEnv(window.env.DATA,
  62 |       process.env.REACT_APP_DATA),
```

I've tried many solutions but have yet to be able to mock the window.env data, how would I do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create React App allows you to [initialize the test environment](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/running-tests#initializing-test-environment) by including a [`src/setupTests.js`](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/running-tests#src-setuptestsjs-1) file that "will be automatically executed before running your tests".

Create React App also sets up the testing environment with `jsdom` which provides the global `window` object.

You can set `window.env` in `src/setupTests.js` and it will be available during your tests:

**src/setupTests.js**

```
window.env = {
  DATA: 'hi'
}
```

**src/code.js**

```
export const getData = () => window.env.DATA
```

**src/code.test.js**

```
import { getData } from './code';

test('env', () => {
  expect(getData()).toBe('hi');  // SUCCESS
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked! Had me stumped for a bit.

Comment: @AndrewObrigewitsch awesome, glad to hear it was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Brian Adams's (also Bryan Adams has great songs!) answer is correct but I wanted to clarify some things. In my case, I tried multiple things but none worked, including Brian's solution. I created the src/setupTests.js file but it seemed like it was not doing anything. After spending hours I realized that I was using react version 17.0.2 and enzyme-adapter version 16.x.x. That was the reason why none of the solutions were working. After installing "@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17" everything started working fine. Settings inside setupTests.js file are automatically applied during the test. So if the solutions that you are trying are not working, make sure that you are using the correct versions of the packages.

Comment: it seems like enzyme is going away and you should probably consider changing over to react testing library
https://dev.to/wojtekmaj/enzyme-is-dead-now-what-ekl

Comment: @hamobi Yes you are right, but in my case, this was an old project that uses react 17.0.2 and someone forgot to upgrade the Enzyme adapter version when they were updating react from 16.x to 17. Not all the existing apps are using the latest versions of the packages available, sometimes you have to use an old version because of the legacy systems. So if anyone else is in a similar situation, my solution might help them. But if they have the option to switch to react testing library then it would be the right move.